# Filter Dataframe, only one row in each weekyear

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = [{'buy_date': '2016-01-19', 'yearweek': 20163, 'buy_price': 228.48}, {'buy_date': '2016-01-20', 'yearweek': 20163, 'buy_price': 219.4}, {'buy_date': '2016-01-21', 'yearweek': 20163, 'buy_price': 220.13}, {'buy_date': '2016-01-22', 'yearweek': 20163, 'buy_price': 221.07}, {'buy_date': '2016-01-25', 'yearweek': 20164, 'buy_price': 218.4}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-01', 'yearweek': 20165, 'buy_price': 218.55}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-02', 'yearweek': 20165, 'buy_price': 213.25}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-03', 'yearweek': 20165, 'buy_price': 210.2}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-04', 'yearweek': 20165, 'buy_price': 215.12}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-05', 'yearweek': 20165, 'buy_price': 211.1}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-08', 'yearweek': 20166, 'buy_price': 212.05}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-16', 'yearweek': 20167, 'buy_price': 199.48}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-17', 'yearweek': 20167, 'buy_price': 207.7}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-18', 'yearweek': 20167, 'buy_price': 210.4}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-19', 'yearweek': 20167, 'buy_price': 208.65}, {'buy_date': '2016-02-22', 'yearweek': 20168, 'buy_price': 205.9}, {'buy_date': '2016-03-02', 'yearweek': 20169, 'buy_price': 216.73}, {'buy_date': '2016-03-03', 'yearweek': 20169, 'buy_price': 224.87}, {'buy_date': '2016-03-04', 'yearweek': 20169, 'buy_price': 225.15}, {'buy_date': '2016-03-08', 'yearweek': 201610, 'buy_price': 227.42}, {'buy_date': '2016-03-09', 'yearweek': 201610, 'buy_price': 226.0}, {'buy_date': '2016-04-11', 'yearweek': 201615, 'buy_price': 225.9}, {'buy_date': '2016-04-12', 'yearweek': 201615, 'buy_price': 231.57}, {'buy_date': '2016-04-13', 'yearweek': 201615, 'buy_price': 233.55}, {'buy_date': '2016-04-18', 'yearweek': 201616, 'buy_price': 231.3}, {'buy_date': '2016-04-20', 'yearweek': 201616, 'buy_price': 233.5}, {'buy_date': '2016-05-26', 'yearweek': 201621, 'buy_price': 184.57}, {'buy_date': '2016-05-27', 'yearweek': 201621, 'buy_price': 189.88}, {'buy_date': '2016-05-30', 'yearweek': 201622, 'buy_price': 189.9}, {'buy_date': '2016-05-31', 'yearweek': 201622, 'buy_price': 191.13}, {'buy_date': '2016-06-01', 'yearweek': 201622, 'buy_price': 199.37}, {'buy_date': '2016-06-02', 'yearweek': 201622, 'buy_price': 204.13}, {'buy_date': '2016-06-03', 'yearweek': 201622, 'buy_price': 204.3}, {'buy_date': '2016-06-06', 'yearweek': 201623, 'buy_price': 201.42}, {'buy_date': '2016-06-07', 'yearweek': 201623, 'buy_price': 205.45}, {'buy_date': '2016-07-04', 'yearweek': 201627, 'buy_price': 210.9}, {'buy_date': '2016-07-05', 'yearweek': 201627, 'buy_price': 214.55}, {'buy_date': '2016-07-07', 'yearweek': 201627, 'buy_price': 210.05}, {'buy_date': '2016-07-11', 'yearweek': 201628, 'buy_price': 214.57}, {'buy_date': '2016-07-12', 'yearweek': 201628, 'buy_price': 217.77}, {'buy_date': '2016-07-13', 'yearweek': 201628, 'buy_price': 217.3}, {'buy_date': '2016-07-15', 'yearweek': 201628, 'buy_price': 220.5}, {'buy_date': '2016-08-01', 'yearweek': 201631, 'buy_price': 228.55}]

df =  pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

In this dataframe how to filter dataframe so for each `yearweek` value have only one date.

Comment: How do you decide which `buy_date` to keep for a given `yearweek`?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC need:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('yearweek')
print (df)
      buy_date  buy_price  yearweek
0   2016-01-19     228.48     20163
4   2016-01-25     218.40     20164
5   2016-02-01     218.55     20165
10  2016-02-08     212.05     20166
11  2016-02-16     199.48     20167
15  2016-02-22     205.90     20168
16  2016-03-02     216.73     20169
19  2016-03-08     227.42    201610
21  2016-04-11     225.90    201615
24  2016-04-18     231.30    201616
26  2016-05-26     184.57    201621
28  2016-05-30     189.90    201622
33  2016-06-06     201.42    201623
35  2016-07-04     210.90    201627
38  2016-07-11     214.57    201628
42  2016-08-01     228.55    201631
```

Another solution should be get [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for `year`s with `yearweek` and aggregate `first`:

```
df['buy_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['buy_date'])

df = df.groupby(df['buy_date'].dt.strftime('%Y%U').rename('YW')).first().reset_index()
print (df)
        YW   buy_date  buy_price  yearweek
0   201603 2016-01-19     228.48     20163
1   201604 2016-01-25     218.40     20164
2   201605 2016-02-01     218.55     20165
3   201606 2016-02-08     212.05     20166
4   201607 2016-02-16     199.48     20167
5   201608 2016-02-22     205.90     20168
6   201609 2016-03-02     216.73     20169
7   201610 2016-03-08     227.42    201610
8   201615 2016-04-11     225.90    201615
9   201616 2016-04-18     231.30    201616
10  201621 2016-05-26     184.57    201621
11  201622 2016-05-30     189.90    201622
12  201623 2016-06-06     201.42    201623
13  201627 2016-07-04     210.90    201627
14  201628 2016-07-11     214.57    201628
15  201631 2016-08-01     228.55    201631
```